# Getting Ext.Ajax is not defined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have been handed over a project which has an availability calender in it.It was working fine 2 days back but suddenly it stopped i dont know what went wrong.But it seems it has to do something with ext.js as it says in the console that
Ext.Ajax is not defined

files of the ext used here are
ext-base.js and ext-all.gz.js

i am new to this framework so i dont know how to use it or if i am using it correctly
or not.When i try to view the
ext-all.gz.js file it doesnt shows in browser console maybe because of the compression
and when i open it at my end it shows me arbitrary binary numbers.
Link to the problem is here http://pinoyrents.com/index.php?opti...t&task=details

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get:

> Failed to load resource: http://pinoyrents.com/RM/system/js/libs/ext/ext-all.gz.js

Fixing this should solve your problem

Comment: Yes i know this..But the problem is i dont have another ext-all.gz.js and cant find it on the net as well.Can you recomment me a place where i can find that?

Comment: It seems to be the problem of .gz.js can any one tell me where i can get new copy?The copy on my server showed arbitrary hexadecimal numbers only

Comment: That seems reasonable to me. The file extension leads to the conclusion that the file is an archive. Try the following commands `mv ext-all.gz.js ext-all.js.gz` and `gunzip ext-all.js.gz`. Now the file should be a normal javascript file, which can be included in your page.